# need help my switch that has to toggle 2 functions

Tags: javascript, function, button, toggle

I've been struggling with my code for the past 2 days. 
And I just can't get my button to work. 
The button is used to control a relay and should toggle between the function to turn it on and the one to turn it off.
It seems to be stuck at the `relayOn` function

Here is my javascript:

```
var a = 1;

function relayOn() {
    hidden = document.getElementById("total");
    hidden.value = "on";
    form = document.getElementById("relay");
    form.method = "GET";
    form.action = "php.php";
    form.submit();
}

function relayOff() {
    hidden = document.getElementById("total");
    hidden.value = "off";
    form = document.getElementById("relay");
    form.method = "GET";
    form.action = "php.php";
    form.submit();
}

$("submitOn").on("click", Toggle);

function Toggle() {
    if (a == 1) {
        a = 2;
        relayOn()
    } else {
        a = 1;
        relayOff()
    }
}
```

And this is the button

```
<input type="button" id="submitOn" style=" top: 200px; border:1px solid #000; font-     size:40px;<?php background-color:green; " value="On" onClick="Toggle()"/>
```

Comment: Why do you add event on button by jQuery **and** `onclick` attribute?

Comment: Can you post the html and javascript in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID selector starts with `#`, and you'd be better off using `data()` than globals

```
$("#submitOn").on("click", function() {
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');

    if ( flag ) {
        relayOff();
    } else {      
        relayOn();
    } 

    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
```

It seems like you could just add it all togheter in the event handler and get

```
$("#submitOn").on("click", function() {
    var flag   = $(this).data('flag'),
        hidden = $('#total'),
        form   = $('#relay');

    hidden.val(flag ? 'off' : 'on');
    form.attr('method', 'GET');
    form.attr('action', 'php.php');
    form.get(0).submit();

    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?
http://jsfiddle.net/zubC6/

```
function relayOn(btn) {
    console.log("ON");
    $(btn).addClass('enabled').removeClass('disabled');
    $("#submitOn").attr('value', 'On');
}

function relayOff(btn) {
    console.log("OFF");
    $(btn).addClass('disabled').removeClass('enabled');
    $("#submitOn").attr('value', 'Off');
}

function toggle() {
    $("#submitOn").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('enabled')) {
            relayOff(this);
        } else {
            relayOn(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Barely tested this code, sorry.